# How to open a project in admin mode without using open from visual studio?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I cannot open the files from visual studio 2010 as below :

[image]

I need to open a project in Admin mode,usually i start visual studio in admin mode and then open project solution.But now i cannot open the project as browse window is not getting opened up.

**How can i open i project in admin mode from visual studio ?**

there is no parallel install.also i can open open other windows like team project and website files.but cannot open solution/files

Comment: Why cannot open projects? What's the problem? Also, maybe "Browse Recent Files" could be handy.

Comment: browse window is not getting poped out !

Comment: To have double-click in explorer open VS in admin mode you would need to change the registry entry to use `runas`. Usually you would do as you say - open VS in admin mode and then open the project. If you say the window is not getting up: Just nothing happens when you do `Ctrl+Shift+O`? Have you installed all VS updates?

Comment: Why do you have to be in admin mode in the first place? If it is a matter of permissions the rectify the file permissions as needed.

Comment: @ZoolWay Ctrl+Shift+O doesnt do the trick as well

Comment: Sorry but I guess if no dialog opens to select the solution to open and no other error message is display, your VS installation seems damaged. Do other open dialogs work? Have you another VS installation in parallel? Like VS 2013?

Comment: there is no parallel install..also i can open open other windows like team project and website files.but cannot open solution/files

Comment: And when you double-click a solution VS starts in no-admin mode but opens the solution or does that also do nothing?

Comment: I believe in you, but maybe it would be good if you include 2 screenshots, one as admin and another one as normal user, to see its differences.

Comment: i cannot even open files while browse in both admin / other mode

Comment: What happens if you drag and drop a solution file from the windows explorer into your empty VS window?

Comment: @ZoolWay a cross sign is shown cannot drag and drop

Comment: I would run a repair on the installation first to rule out some problem with Visual Studio...

Comment: repaired already .@Baldrick